# Recursive descent parser, initialization of variable with itself, dilemma

Tags: c++, parsing, ambiguity, recursive-descent

I want to know whether conforming C++ compiler is required to support the following code:

```
int a(a);      // no other a is visible, we mean initialization of a with itself
```

Visual Studio 2013 does not support it (undeclared identifier), however some other compilers compile it.

And here is our dilemma: for possible expression check we need to dispose information about `a` (including its type) since it can be part of expression, however there is another possibility that it is function, in this case we are only constructing type expression (and symbol `a` is probably not in the symbol table yet).

I think that recursive descent parser is more likely to run in this dilemma, since it is very structural in nature and supporting this specific case will be like a special 'crutch' (type expression is being constructed when we encounter `a` inside `()` and we are at some level of recursion). So I assume that visual studio uses recursive descent strategy.

So with all this in mind, whether it is worth compiler writer's effort and whether it is justified to support such code (especially when using recursive descent)?

Comment: You have UB to initialize `a` with a not yet initialized `a`.

Comment: but you can have `void* p(&p); // Has its own address`.

Comment: The example `int x = x;` in 3.3.2 seems to indicate, that this is legal and a conforming compiler must accept it. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf

Comment: Yes, it is UB, but it does not answer the question whether conforming C++ compiler is required to support such code and does not highlight this dilemma from compiler writer's point of view.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's even possible to write a recursive descent C++ parser.

Comment: With reference to @user657267 answer below its valid for compiler to support such code, but person writing such code roughly needs to understand that the variable will not be assigned any memory till ';' is seen by compiler. So, supporting such code is worth from compiler writer point of view w.r.t correctness but not worth from code writer's point of view.

Comment: @molbdnilo GCC uses hand written recursive descent C++ parser, so it is not something miraculous.

Comment: @igntec Embarassing that I didn't check. I'll go and hide in the corner now.

Answer (score 1):

[basic.scope.pdecl]

> The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as
>   noted below. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> unsigned char x = 12;
> { unsigned char x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. *—end example*]

In `int a(a);`, the declarator ends at the opening brace of the initializer, so yes, compilers are required to allow this (GCC helpfully gives an `-Wuninitialized` warning if it's an automatic variable).

Comment: Correct, with recursive descent parsing, encountering first '('  will correspond to declaration of "integer variable" and so by now "a" is familiar to compiler. But there will be more productions which direct compiler to generate initialization code for this variable on seeing '('. By now, since "a" is familiar so no problem in using it as a value inside "()" although it will hold garbage value.

Comment: What about this:   `struct abc{
        int v;
        abc()
        {
                v = 12349; cout << "abc()" << endl;
        }
        abc(int c)
        {
                v = c; cout << "abc(int)" << endl;
        }
}; `  `abc a(a.v)`  What all are going to be printed?

Comment: @sameerkn: UB, you call `abc(int)` with an uninitialized `int` that you read.